# create a map with D3 but the data of countries are not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, d3.js

i have create a map with D3 from a topojson but in html data of the countries have not displayed.

Hello everybody!

i have genarated a map of Europe with d3 from topojson file.
This is my code

```
const svg =d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

const projection = d3.geoMercator().scale(600).center([13.439235,48.830666])
.translate([width / 2, height / 2]); // translate map to svg;

const path=d3.geoPath(projection);
const g = svg.append('g');

d3.json('./europe.topojson')
.then(data =>{
  const countries = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.europe);
  console.log(countries);
  g.selectAll('path').data(countries.features).enter().append('path').attr('class', 'country').attr('d', path);
```

The topojson file is something like that:

```
{"type":"Topology","objects":
{"europe":
{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"MultiPolygon",
"properties":{"NAME":"Azerbaijan"},"id":"AZ","arcs":[[[0,1,2]],[[3]],[[4]],[[5,6,7,8,9,10],[11]]]},
{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"NAME":"Albania"},"id":"AL","arcs":[[12,13,14,15,16,17,18]]},
{"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"NAME":"Armenia"},"id":"AM","arcs":[[[-12]],[[19,-3,20,21,-7],[-5],[-4]]]},
{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"NAME":"Bosnia and Herzegovina"},"id":"BA","arcs":[[22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]]},

...
```

-and goes on for all countries-

The map appears in my browser but with no data attributes (name, id ).

When i *console.log(countries)*  the console prints data from topojson, such as name , id etc.
This is from console:

```
0
: 
{type: 'Feature', id: 'AZ', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
1
: 
{type: 'Feature', id: 'AL', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
2
: 
{type: 'Feature', id: 'AM', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
3
: 
{type: 'Feature', id: 'BA', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
```

Do you have any idea;

Comment: Hey there! Your code samples as posted are a bit hard to read. It seems like your `then` handler in your code is incomplete? Could you edit your question and format your samples properly so they can be understood more easily?

Comment: hey i edited the topojson file.. 
The first is the whole code i wrote to create the map.
The third is the output from the console.log(coutries)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you expect to see the properties of each feature. In the code you shared, you are never using that data.

If all you want is some labels you might follow this example

https://observablehq.com/@rahulbot/us-map-with-labels

Comment: In the topojson for each country have some properties like name, id..
 i expect to see these properties when d3 drawing the map, in  html -svg-   tag inside paths who represent the countries.

Comment: @Coco For that, you will need to manually append a "text" SVG element for each feature, and for that I highly recommend following the example above, if you have any other specific questions, you can create a new post any time! If this answer helped/worked, please upvote and select it as the solution :)

Comment: i dont want labels or something like that. 
I downloaded an free svg map and i place inside svg tag (inside countries paths) id, Name  eg <path id="FR" name="France" class= "mycountries" ..> so if i want to select any country , i can select this by ID.

The topojson file has these  identifiers like "name" "id" but when i load this in D3 and D3 draw the map , id Name do not exist.
My question is How can i fix this.

Comment: @Coco Is your problem that the name doesn't render, or that it's not present as an attribute in the path element?

Comment: yes! name or id (or some other properties that i could put in properties of topojson file to help me selecting spesific countries)

Comment: @Coco https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/d3-js-selection-attr-function/ does this help? You can do `.attr("name", d => d.properties.NAME)`